# Mysterious failure to write to Quickbooks using QB Java SDK v3

Tags: java, google-app-engine, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm writing a web application using the Google App Engine, and I'm attempting to save some data in Quickbooks, using the Quickbooks Java SDK. I'm getting an exception that I know nothing about when I try to add a customer:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key request.source.header
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:395)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:355)
at com.intuit.ipp.util.PropertyHelper.init(PropertyHelper.java:60)
at com.intuit.ipp.util.PropertyHelper.getInstance(PropertyHelper.java:44)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.ConnectionInterceptor.populateRequestHeaders(ConnectionInterceptor.java:187)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.ConnectionInterceptor.execute(ConnectionInterceptor.java:137)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeRequestInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:76)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:62)
at com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService.add(DataService.java:108)
```

This is on the deployed version of the app. When I run the app locally on my own machine, the exception differs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.ConnectionInterceptor.getRetryHandler(ConnectionInterceptor.java:212)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.ConnectionInterceptor.execute(ConnectionInterceptor.java:85)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeRequestInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:76)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:62)
at com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService.add(DataService.java:108)
```

I haven't found anyone having similar problems. Mind you, this whole thing worked using QB SDK v2, no exceptions thrown.

So, does anyone have any bright ideas about the nature of my problem?

**Edit**: I included the QBHelper JAR as well, and now the issue seems to be that com.intuit.ipp.exceptions.FMSException can't be found. I'm looking right at it! It's in the build path.

Comment: your api resource is not found. may be .properties file or something. are you sure, you download full api??

Comment: How would I know whether my API is the "full" API? Also, what do you mean about a .properties file?

Answer (score 0):

This issue generally comes when you have multiple versions of java devkit added in the same project. [ In my case, I had added v2 and v3 devkit jars in the same project. I had to add v3 jar before v2 in the classpath ]

Please use only ipp-java-devkit-2.0.11-jar-with-dependencies.jar [ Please download the latest version from docs site. ]

Thanks

Comment: The newest devkit that I can find is 2.0.0. Where did you find 2.0.11?

Comment: Also, I do only have v3 devkit, not v2 anymore.

Comment: I was referring to V2 devkit which had the version 2.0.11.
There is a similar jar ( with-all-dependencies ) in V3(2.0.0) as well. Try to use only that jar( please remove data and devkit jar from your classpath and try).

Comment: Okay. I've removed all of the other Quickbooks JARs from the build path. Now there is only ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar. I continue to get the following exceptions:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intuit/ipp/exception/FMSException
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException

Comment: (Also, I tried removing that JAR and instead using shaded-dependencies-2.0.0-shaded.jar. The results were identical.)

Comment: You can use only ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

Comment: Ah. I was unclear about that. I did remove all of the other QB JARs from the build path and tried using only ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar. Still, I get these problems with a missing FMSException.